# Python 2.7 statsmodels predict error: TypeError

Tags: python, statsmodels, predict

I have data in a pandas dataframe on which I created a model. This data has the fields 'gestation' and 'BMI'. For modelling and predicting I have the following code:

```
############################################################
import statsmodels as sm
import statsmodels.api as sma

model = sma.OLS.from_formula("gestation ~ BMI", data = gest)
result = model.fit()
############################################################
```

The params retrieved with result.params gives me:

Regressionkoeffizienten:
    'Intercept    241.781'
    'BMI            1.818'

Now I am trying to predict some values to check the accuracy of the model:

```
############################################################
exog = dict(BMI = [BMW, np.mean(gest_nied.BMI), np.mean(gest_hoch.BMI)])
print "exog = ", exog
print "Vorhersage: ", result.predict(exog)
############################################################
```

The output shows the following:

```
'exog =  {'BMI': [20.248580968280468, 16.784782608695654, 21.349090909090904]}'

'Vorhersage:'
  'Traceback (most recent call last):'
    'File "Gestation.py", line 424, in <module>'
      'print "Vorhersage: ", result.predict(exog)'
    'File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 774, in predict'
      'if len(exog) < len(exog_index):'
    'TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()'
```

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Further information (added at 09h56 on 26/07/2017).
I finally got the prediction to work, though not exactly as I wanted, by changing to the following code:

```
print "Vorhersage: ", np.round(model.predict(result.params, exog=[[1,18],[1,21]]), 3)
```

I then tried the original code by adding the result.params as parameter as follows:

```
exog = dict(BMI = [BMW, np.mean(gest_nied.BMI), np.mean(gest_hoch.BMI)])
print "exog = ", exog
print "Vorhersage: ", result.predict(result.params, exog)
```

Unfortunately I then got NaN as output for both the values (Intercept and BMI). So still not working as expected.

OK, I found one problem: I should be calling predict() on the model and not on the result. Unfortunately both

```
model.predict(exog)
```

and

```
model.predict(result.params, exog)
```

has a problem with exog being a dict, giving me the following output:

```
'exog =  {'BMI': [20.248580968280468, 16.784782608695654, 21.349090909090904]}'
'Vorhersage:'
'Traceback (most recent call last):'
  'File "Gestation.py", line 409, in <module>'
    'print "Vorhersage: ", model.predict(result.params, exog)'
  'File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 261, in predict'
    'return np.dot(exog, params)'
'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'float''
```

I then changed the code as follows:

```
exog = [[1, BMW], [1, np.mean(gest_nied.BMI)], [1, np.mean(gest_hoch.BMI)]]
print "exog = ", exog
print "Vorhersage: ", model.predict(result.params, exog)
```

This is just about as close as I will get to what I really want, but the main thing is it is working.

Comment: which statsmodels version? This is most likely a bug, that assumes that the exog in predict also has a pandas index. Convert the exog dict to a pandas DataFrame, or maybe Series as work around.

Comment: The version is 0.8.0rc1. I got it working by using the following line of code:
    model.predict(result.params, exog=[[1,18],[1,21]])

With this the prediction works as expected. I still need to try to add the BMI data as in the description above, though.